# Is a root certificate CA required on the client side to establish an HTTPS connection with server?

Tags: powershell, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I have a PowerShell script that creates a root key, root pem, and root cert:
(Some boilplate code and checks are hidden from the code below)

1. Generating an encrypted private key
2. Creating a private .pem file
3. Creating a private CA .crt file

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:$RootPass -out $root_key $key_bit_len
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key $root_key -sha256 -days $Duration -out $root_cert -passin pass:$RootPass -subj $subj_info_private
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key $root_key -sha512 -days $Duration -out $root_pem -passin pass:$RootPass -subj $subj_info_private
```

This is then used to to sign a server certificate by:

1. Making a server key file
2. Creating a Cert Signing Request File
3. Creating a server Certificate .crt file
4. Converting the .crt to .pfx

```
openssl genrsa -out $server_key $key_bit_len
openssl req -new -key $server_key -out $server_csr -subj $subj_info_public
openssl x509 -req -in $server_csr -CA $root_pem -CAkey $root_key -CAcreateserial -out $server_cert -days $Duration -sha512 -extfile $ext_file -extensions 'req_ext' -passin pass:$RootPass
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey $server_key -in $server_cert -passout pass:$PFXExportPass -name $PersonalCommonName -out $server_pfx
```

Now on my server, I can install the root certificate into the trusted root CA store and the server (personal) certificate in the personal store.

For this server to communicate securely with a client, does the client have to have the same root certificate installed? Or is there something I'm not understanding, like making a client key as shown on [mariaDB website](https://mariadb.com/docs/ent/security/data-in-transit-encryption/create-self-signed-certificates-keys-openssl/#:%7E:text=ca%2Dkey.pem-,Verifying%20the%20Certificates,-Verify%20the%20server). I'm trying to understand the technicalities of SSL certificates to know if I need to distribute a <s>private key</s>private CA certificate to various clients (In my case EC2 instances that communicate with the central server) or if there  are other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificates are used to authenticate a site, i.e. to make sure that one is actually talking to the expected server and not some man in the middle.

In order to verify a certificate one needs to be sure among others that the certificate is issued for the site visited (i.e. the domain in the URL) and that it is issued by a trusted CA. If the check for a trusted CA would not be done than a man in the middle could just issue a fake certificate for the site by its own CA.

The trusted CA must be known to the client up-front, i.e. the server can not simply send it within the TLS handshake since the TLS handshake is not trusted. If the client would simply trust a CA send inside a TLS handshake then a man in the middle attacker could provide its own CA there.

If the certificates was issued by a public CA the usually the client already knows and trusts this CA. If you use your own CA instead you somehow need to put this CA into the clients trust store before the TLS connection can be established and the certificate properly verified.

Comment: Just to clarify, you do *not* need to install the private key on the client machines. You *do* need to install the root CA's issuing cert into the Trusted Root store on the client machines accessing the site. As somebody who runs the Public Key Infrastructure in multiple environments for my company that issues TLS certs for web services used internally, we push the root cert and intermediate certs to the appropriate stores via GPO. For sites accessed by external resources we use certs issued by a public CA.

Comment: I see, so a public CA (like digicert) often has their private certificates (called public CA) already preinstalled on many machines.  In my case, the private CA I make has to be on the server and the client. The server also needs a Server Cert generated from the private CA. All of this to prove who is at the end of a line of communication and encrypt traffic between the two parties.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: No, you do not need to install intermediate certs on any client machine, nor should you. You only need to install the CA root certificate. All other certs in the chain, including any intermediate certs, should be supplied by the the server during the handshake.

Comment: @Lacrosse343: There is no benefit to having the root CA installed on the server, unless your server requires TLS client auth.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Okay I think I better understand; The client needs a Root CA to verify the server. The server needs a certificate signed by the root CA on the client. Then after that, it can get more complicated if the server creates another intermediate ca and certificate that is given to the client during the handshake. Thanks!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk So on the server, even though the windows certificate manager says "the issuer of this certificate could not be found" since the root CA is not on the server machine, it can still communicate with the clients?

Comment: @Lacrosse343: if the root CA is not known to the client then it can still communicate if the warning gets ignored. But in this case one cannot be sure that one is actually communicating with the expected server or instead some attacker.